# Using map on Scala with option return types

Tags: scala, future, scala-option

say I have a function that takes in some kind of Option[]...
namely:

```
def help(x: Int, 
         y : Option[BigInteger], 
         ec: ExecutionContext, 
         sc: SecurityContext): Future[Long] = { ... }
```

and I have an object that calls on it with map, say

```
val answerList: List[Future[Long]] =  random.getPersons
       .map(p => help(x , myY, ec, sc))
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

where I have "myY" it says that

> Type mismatch, expected Option[BigInteger], actual: BigInteger.

I see where this is coming as my help method made the type Option.

I tried casting myY by doing Option[myY] but that doesn't seem to help. Assuming help method is implemented correctly, can someone please help me out or point me to the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that `myY` is a BigInteger, then all you need to do is call help with `Option(myY)` instead of `myY`

Comment: Also, if `myY` is guaranteed to be non-null, it might make sense to use a more specific `Option` constructor - i.e. `Some(myY)`